# Using Deface to prepopulate Billing Address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, deface

I am trying to populate my billing address with prepopulated values.
I have written a deface as :

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => 'spree/address/_form',
                                  :name => 'prepopulate_billing_address',
                                  :set_attributes => 'p#order_bill_address_attributes_phone',
                                  :attributes => {:value => "122344"}
                                  )
```

and the content belongs to `app/overrides/autofill_billing_address.rb`

I am trying to replace this view 
[Spree form view](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/frontend/app/views/spree/address/_form.html.erb)

with the above deface but the deface logs say

```
Deface: 'prepopulate_billing_address' matched 0 times with 'p#order_bill_address_attributes_phone'
```

The id from the spree instance running is `order_bill_address_attributes_phone` and is wrapped in `<p>`.
Any idea? Thanks for the help!

Comment: try to disable this overriding, load the page and try to find in browser console `$('p#order_bill_address_attributes_phone')`

Comment: $('#order_bill_address_attributes_phone') answers but that didn't work too, that;s when I added the p attribute.

Comment: AFAIK Deface is applied to erb template (that's why you can target erb code), so when your override is being iterpreted there is no such thing as `p#order_bill_address_attributes_phone`. Unfortunately I never succeeded in such interpreted deface, I always replace whole partial with my changes, but that's more like workaround, not solution.

Comment: But in spree view customization documentation,they have given an example :insert_after => “div#wow p.header” which made me think perhaps the element wrapped in plays a role too. Still, not a lot of documentation around and really less clarity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
Deface::Override.new :virtual_path => 'spree/address/_form',
                     :name => 'prepopulate_billing_address',
                     :replace => 'code[erb-loud]:contains("phone_field :phone")',
                     :text => "<%= form.phone_field :phone, :class => 'required', :value => '122344' %>"
```

One helpful thing is to use the rake tasks for testing what matches what:

```
rake deface:test_selector['spree/address/_form','code[erb-loud]:contains("phone_field :phone")']
```

You can see that your selectors from before wouldn't work because this:

```
rake deface:test_selector['spree/address/_form','p']
```

returns:

```
# snip
---------------- Match 10 ----------------
<p class="field" id='<%="#{address_id}phone" %>'>
    <%= form.label :phone, Spree.t(:phone) %><span class="required">*</span><br><%= form.phone_field :phone, :class => 'required', :value => '122334' %>
  </p>
# snip
```

At this point the ID hasn't been set yet because as zrl3dx  mentioned, you're operating on the erb before it's been evaluated.

Comment: yes, I didn't know a rake task existed, never found this in documentation. Saves a lot of time. By the way, what does code[erb-loud]:contains tell deface? I don't find it in the views. Also, phone_field is just a placeholder right? Because I cannot connect that to the view too. And thanks a ton gmacdougall!!

Comment: The code[erb-loud]:contains matches an erb tag which contains the text listed.  Specifically, I'm trying to match this line from the template: https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.0.4/frontend/app/views/spree/address/_form.html.erb#L67